# Flask/Python modify JSON output

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working on DataTables table to display large table from mySQL using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have this flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://admin:pass@10.10.99.11/test1'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class table1(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'table1'
   id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first = db.Column('firstname', db.String(2))
   last = db.Column('lastname', db.String(2))

   def __init__(self, first, last):
      self.first = first
      self.last = last
      pass

   @property
   def serialize(self):
      return {
         'id': self.id,
         'first': self.first,
         'last': self.last
      }


tick = table1.query.all()
data=[i.serialize for i in tick]

# I HAVE TRIED THIS ROUTES WITH DIFFERENT APPROACH, BUT NONE WORKED FOR ME
@app.route('/tickets')
def get_tickets():
   return jsonify(data)

@app.route('/users')
def get_users():
   return jsonify(myData=[i.serialize for i in tick])

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
   return render_template('data.html',data=jsonify(data))

@app.route("/api/result")
def result_json():
   data=dict(data=[i.serialize for i in tick])
   return render_template('data.html', data=data)
```

It sends this valid JSON to my html:

```
[
  {'id': 1, 'last': 'Spelec', 'first': 'Anton'}, 
  {'id': 2, 'last': 'Pilcher', 'first': 'Rosamunde'}, 
  {'id': 3, 'last': 'Burian', 'first': 'Vlasta'}
]
```

**The problem is, that I need to have this code within {"data": ... }.** Is it possible to add it to JSON in flask?

When I use `return jsonify(data=[i.serialize for i in tick])` instead of `return render_template('data.html', data=data)`, I get as a result

```
{"data":
 [
  {"first":"Anton","id":1,"last":"Spelec"},
  {"first":"Rosamunde","id":2,"last":"Pilcher"},
  {"first":"Vlasta","id":3,"last":"Burian"}
 ]
}
```

but without render_template the html page isn't displayed. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You want to make a dictionary e.g `data=dict(data=[i.serialize for i in tick])` and pass that in `render_template`. This way you have data serialized similar to the JSON  you want as a result

Comment: Thank you, Oluwafemi, it's working. Please create answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary with `data` key *e.g.*

```
# Using dict function syntax
data=dict(data=[i.serialize for i in tick])

# Using dictional literal syntax
data={'data': [i.serialize for i in tick]}
```

Then pass `data` as a context argument in `render_template`

```
...
return render_template('data.html', data=data)
```

This way data is serialised similar to the JSON you want as a result.